# MAV simulation environment with gripper

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-noetic

I need a gripper with MAV for a pick up and drop simulation. Does anyone know of any resources that I can use right off the bat, or with minor changes?

I could find standalone gripper urdf; I did try integrating with the rotors_simulator. The MAV drifts in one direction and, does to-fro motion eventually going haywire. I tried reducing the masses to 1e^-6 (lowest permissible value for links to have joints), but the problem persists. I believe the center of mass is not aligning, but I expected the controller to be robust enough to handle that.
(Gripper module I am using - https://github.com/ekorudiawan/rg2_simulation)

Comment: Welcome to RSE. Please give us more context, which packages and plugins at which version you are using, and possibly provide the full model for your simulation.